# Markit PMI vs ISM PMI

Tags: index

What is the difference between the Markit Manufacturing PMI and the ISM Manufacturing PMI? The monthly number differs a lot, my understanding is that they are trying to indicate the same thing.

Comment: According to  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purchasing_Managers_Index  there are two general providers for the PMI index. The Markit Group and the Institute of Supply Management. The statement is the same but the providers are different and thus the numbers could also differ

Answer (score 1):

http://www.calculatedriskblog.com/2012/12/manufacturing-ism-pmi-vs-markit.html

Two similiar barometers with different weights

Comment: can you please give a definition of the meaning and composition of these?